# Unix : parse a csv ( actually semi colon) separated file, incrementing each date field by one day

Tags: parsing, unix, date, csv, increment

I've searched high and low for something that will do this. 
I thought it would be relatively straight forward.

I've used bash script containing awk to replace a date in a specific column, but I don't know how to automatically identify a date field, increment the date intelligently, and write the odified date back to the file. Each row contains 30 column approximately, and approximately ten contain dates in dd.mm.YYYY format.

Any thoughts on approaches appreciated.

Comment: I don't have access to Perl. I am confortable with bash. Sample: `COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4;COL5;COL6;COL7;COL8;COL9;COL10;COL11;COL12;COL13;COL14;COL15;COL16;COL17;COL18;COL19;COL20;COL21;COL22;COL23;COL24;COL25;COL26;COL27
1234567;12345;Abc;123;12345678999;ABC;1234-123456-12-123;1234567;15.11.2012;15.11.2012;31.01.2013;10.01.2011;10.01.2014;10.01.2013;10.01.2014;;Abc/123;1A;;0;0;Abcdef;15.01.2014;15.01.2014;ABC;-123456789;05.02.2013`

Comment: If you're so *comfortable* with bash just go ahead and do what you want. We thought that you have a problem, but maybe we misread your question. I am comfortable enough with `bash`, but I would use a scripting language here, too.

Comment: Are you hard of comprehending.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a script (Perl?) to doe this and use that scripting language's date libraries (e.g. [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.38/lib/Date/Manip.pod)) to handle the dates intelligently. Perl (or your own favorite scripting language) should be able to handle all of the complexities of opening a file, reading/parsing, doing the date manipulation and re-writing without spawning off other processes etc.

Edit: re your comment above, what sort of Unix do you have that you don't have access to Perl/Python/Ruby etc.?

Comment: `COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4;COL5;COL6;COL7;COL8;COL9;COL10;COL11;COL12;COL13;COL14;COL15;COL16;COL17;COL18;COL19;COL20;COL21;COL22;COL23;COL24;COL25;COL26;COL27
1234567;12345;Abc;123;12345678999;ABC;1234-123456-12-123;1234567;15.11.2012;15.11.2012;31.01.2013;10.01.2011;10.01.2014;10.01.2013;10.01.2014;;Abc/123;1A;;0;0;Abcdef;15.01.2014;15.01.2014;ABC;-123456789;05.02.2013
`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS=FS=";"
}

{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {

        dx = mktime(gensub(/(..)\.(..)\.(....)/, "\\3 \\2 \\1 0 0 0", "", $i)) + 86400

        $i = (dx == "86399" ? $i : strftime("%d.%m.%Y", dx))
    }
}1
```

Contents of `file`:

```
COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4;COL5;COL6;COL7;COL8;COL9;COL10;COL11;COL12;COL13;COL14;COL15;COL16;COL17;COL18;COL19;COL20;COL21;COL22;COL23;COL24;COL25;COL26;COL27 1234567;12345;Abc;123;12345678999;ABC;1234-123456-12-123;1234567;15.11.2012;15.11.2012;31.01.2013;10.01.2011;10.01.2014;10.01.2013;10.01.2014;;Abc/123;1A;;0;0;Abcdef;15.01.2014;15.01.2014;ABC;-123456789;05.02.2013
```

Results:

```
COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4;COL5;COL6;COL7;COL8;COL9;COL10;COL11;COL12;COL13;COL14;COL15;COL16;COL17;COL18;COL19;COL20;COL21;COL22;COL23;COL24;COL25;COL26;COL27 1234567;12345;Abc;123;12345678999;ABC;1234-123456-12-123;1234567;16.11.2012;16.11.2012;01.02.2013;11.01.2011;11.01.2014;11.01.2013;11.01.2014;;Abc/123;1A;;0;0;Abcdef;16.01.2014;16.01.2014;ABC;-123456789;06.02.2013
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F ";" '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { dx = mktime(gensub(/(..)\.(..)\.(....)/, "\\3 \\2 \\1 0 0 0", "", $i)) + 86400; $i = (dx == "86399" ? $i : strftime("%d.%m.%Y", dx)) } }1' OFS=";" file
```

To overwrite the original file, use redirection:

```
awk -f script.awk file > temp && mv temp file
```